# Passing FieldNames and Values dynamically to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to pass FieldName as a string into Method that updates a table.  I have looked at Linq.Expressions but this doesn't seem to expose all the details I need about the field Name and dataType and I don't really want to go through the existing string builder solution that executes a sql command directly.

```
    public static Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "laststoragefullalert", DateTime.Now);
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "numberofalerts", int(tooMany);
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "lastalertmessage", "Oops");
    }

    public static void UpdateLicenceField(int LicenceID, string FieldName, object value)
    {
        using (myContext db = new MyContext())
        {
            Licence licence = db.Licence.Where(x => x.ID == LicenceID && 
                  x.Deleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
            // so db.Licence has fields .laststoragefullalert .numberofalerts .lastalertmessage 
            // (in real life this has hundred of settings and we very often just want to update one)
            // I'm tring to get a single Method that will act dynamically like the current ADO function that creates a SQL string and executes that. 
            // 1. check that the FieldName type is the same type as the object passed in value.
            // 2. update that FieldName with value and Saves the Licence table.

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are looking for* Reflection. yourObject.GetType().GetProperty(propName) will give you a PropertyInfo that contains all you need :)

Comment: Perhaps consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for string based LINQ. Also, updating one field of a time is a terrible idea, each one is going to cause multiple server communications and your code has no need for string fieldnames. Update the fields on the retrieved object directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" library from https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and use:

```
Licence licence = db.Licence.Where(FieldName + "==@0", fieldValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

or use a method like this:

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetPredicate(string methodName, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "type");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(string) });
    if (method == null)
    {
        var containsMethods = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(m => m.Name == methodName);
        foreach (var m in containsMethods)
        {
            if (m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            {
                method = m;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp);
}

Licence licence = db.Licence.Where(GetPredicate("Contains", fieldName, fieldValue)).FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your responses.  Using a bit from both Renan and Roberto's reply I put something together that does the job.  It's obviously not ideal to update in this way but this is instead of having  50 or 60 functions with similar code within an automated process.  There's still error checking and validations to be added but this will reduce my codebase considerably.
Thanks again Glenn.

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "LastStorageFullAlert", DateTime.Now);
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "IsProcessing", true);
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "RegSource", "this is a string");
        UpdateLicenceField(2284, "ProcessFilesDelay", 200);

        return 1;
    }

    public static void UpdateLicenceField(int LicenceID, string Field, object Value)
    {
        using (BACCloudModel BACdb = new BACCloudModel())
        {
            Licence licence = BACdb.Licence.Where(x => x.ID == LicenceID && x.Deleted == false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (licence != null)
            {
                var fieldvalue = licence.GetType().GetProperty(Field);
                var ftype = fieldvalue.PropertyType;
                var vtype = Value.GetType();

                if (ftype == vtype)
                {
                    object[] Values = { Value };  
                    licence.GetType().GetProperty(Field).SetMethod.Invoke(licence, Values);
                    BACdb.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```